# Let $a, b, c>0$, such that $a+b+c=1$, prove that $\frac{a}{(b+c)^2}+\frac{b}{(a+c)^2}+\frac{c}{(a+b)^2}\ge\frac{9}{4}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a, b, c>0$, such that $a+b+c=1$, prove that:
$$\frac{a}{(b+c)^2}+\frac{b}{(a+c)^2}+\frac{c}{(a+b)^2}\ge\frac{9}{4}$$

Comment: Please add some context (why do you need this solved, what methods do you know/are supposed to use) and show your own attempts if any were made. It will help others give you an answer most suited to your case

Comment: To complete <<@YuriyS's comment, the answer could be completely different if it is a PreCalculus or a Calculus question.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $$\frac{a}{(b+c)^2}+\frac{b}{(a+c)^2}+\frac{c}{(a+b)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{a}{(1-a)^2}+\frac{b}{(1-b)^2}+\frac{c}{(1-c)^2}$$
Let $f(t)=\frac t{1-t^2}$
Use Jensen's Inequality

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
  & A=\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}=\frac{{{a}^{2}}}{ab+ac}+\frac{{{b}^{2}}}{bc+ab}+\frac{{{c}^{2}}}{ac+bc} \\ 
\\
 & [(ab+ac)+(bc+ab)+(ac+bc)]A\ge {{(a+b+c)}^{2}} \\ 
\\
 & (2ab+2bc+2ca)A\ge 1 \\ 
\\
 & A\ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{(2ab+2bc+2ca)}=\frac{1}{(2ab+2bc+2ca)}\ge \frac{3}{2} \\ 
\\
 & (a+b+c)\left( \frac{a}{{{(b+c)}^{2}}}+\frac{b}{{{(c+a)}^{2}}}+\frac{c}{{{(a+b)}^{2}}} \right)\ge \left( \frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b} \right)^2\ge \frac{9}{4} \\ 
\end{align}